# How should I propagate Ajuga

Tags: propagation, ground-cover

A few years back I removed a shady patch of lawn and planted it to ground cover plants. One half was planted to Lamium, the other half to *[Ajuga Reptans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajuga_reptans)*. In the years since the Ajuga has taken off and carpeted it's area, meanwhile the Lamium has limped along and struggled to get going. I'm considering killing off what's left of the Lamium and replacing it with more Ajuga, but how best to do it?

I think it should be possible to divide the existing plants and transplant half, but I want to be sure it won't damage them too much. I know it spreads by runners (rather aggressively), but my previous efforts to pull up the younger runners and move them haven't been very successful, they seem to dry up before they really get going.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ajuga is fairly shallow rooted. You should be able to take a sharp spade and cut out 6" wide squares.  Plant in the new area.  Top dress where you made the cut and then stand back, way back as it spreads even more.

I too have found Lamium does not deserve it's reputation as a good groundcover in Ontario.  Summers are too hot and the soil gets too dry.  It ends looking rather sad in August.  If you don't want an all Ajuga bed you could consider top dressing the Lamium and watering more during the hot months which some years are July and August.